# How do you set a path in Telerik RadFileExplorer to be Read Only?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, web-services, telerik

Right now, I have a RadFileExplorer from Telerik set up on my website. I select a bunch of files and perform various operations on them. One of the operations is a client side event where any files that have been 'translated' get moved into a sub directory.

I want my customers to be able to view this sub directory but not do anymore operations on the files within it. So, to clarify. They can do operations on files in one folder, but not a folder within that folder.

I can't find any documentation or help on Telerik's forums.

Thanks, Guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folder permissions are inherited from what you set in the ViewPaths, DeletePaths and UploadPaths properties. In order to change them for child folders you would need a custom content provider that will give you the desired functionality. You can find examples how to implement one in the following resources:

http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/fileexplorer.aspx

[http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-ajax/file-explorer.aspx](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-ajax/file-explorer.aspxa)

and more precisely this one:

http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/fileexplorer/physical-paths-and-different-content-types.aspx

This article explains thins in greater detail:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/fileexplorer-custom-filebrowsercontentprovider.html